# Torch C++: Getting the value of a int tensor by using *.data<int>()

Tags: c++, pytorch, torch, libtorch

In the C++ version of Libtorch, I found that I can get the value of a float tensor by `*tensor_name[0].data<float>()`, in which instead of `0` I can use any other valid index. But, when I have defined an `int` tensor by adding option `at::kInt` into the tensor creation, I cannot use this structure to get the value of the tensor, i.e. something like `*tensor_name[0].data<at::kInt>()` or `*tensor_name[0].data<int>()` does not work and the debugger keeps saying that `Couldn't find method at::Tensor::data<at::kInt>` or `Couldn't find method at::Tensor::data<int>`.
I can get the values by `auto value_array = tensor_name=accessor<int,1>()`, but it was easier to use `*tensor_name[0].data<int>()`. Can you please let me know how I can use `data<>()` to get the value of an `int` tensor?

I also have a same problem with `bool` type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `item<dtype>()` to get a scalar out of a Tensor.

```
int main() {
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::randint(20, {2, 3});
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;
  int a = tensor[0][0].item<int>();
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

~/l/build ❯❯❯ ./example-app
  3  10   3
  2   5   8
[ Variable[CPUFloatType]{2,3} ]
3
```

The following code prints `0` (tested on Linux with the stable libtorch):

```
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <iostream>                                     

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])                  
{
    auto indx = torch::zeros({20},at::dtype(at::kLong));
    std::cout << indx[0].item<long>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have `auto indx =torch::zeros({batch_size},at::dtype(at::kLong));` and then `p indx[0].item<long>()` gives me `Couldn't find method at::Tensor::item<long>`. Also, it comes with types like `Byte`, I even do not have same type in C++, and `bool` just does not work.

Comment: These commands work well for me on Linux and the stable libtorch.

Comment: So, you are saying `auto indx =torch::zeros({batch_size},at::dtype(at::kLong));` and `p indx[0].item<long>()` works well for you, right? I am also using the stable version on Linux. So, what is the difference?

Comment: I see. Now, I have another problem. `cout` works fine, during the debug time, `gdb` cannot execute this code, which is weird. Do you have any idea about it?